# Simple minimization not evaluating

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I tried to solve a rather simple optimization problem, which Mathematica apparently cannot handle. A minimal example is the following:

```
Minimize[{a^2*Exp[-b^2], b > 0}, a, Reals]

(* Minimize[{a^2 E^-b^2, b > 0}, a, Reals] *)
```

Obviously, the answer should have been `{0, {a -> 0}}`. The minimization works when I drop the exponential term. My Mathematica version is `10.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (July 29, 2015)`.

Are there any options I need to set to aid Mathematica in solving the above minimization or is this simply a bug, which I should report to Wolfram?

Comment: Have a look at `NMinimize`.

Comment: Well, I have a more complicated expression with more parameters and I'd like to get the minimum as a function of these parameters. I also believe that the above minimization is simple enough that it could be solved analytically.

Comment: If your expression is non polynomial I don't think `Minimize` will handle it.

Comment: I understand that non-linear optimization is hard, but there are a couple of examples in the documentation. Also my optimization problem is polynomial in `a`, the parameter I optimize for. It would be sufficient if the function realizes that the factor `Exp[-b^2]` is non-negative.

Comment: If you replace `Exp[-b^2]` with `c`, then you get an answer (although if you put in the constraint `c > 0`, that seems to be ignored).  As @b.gatessucks states, Minimize seems to only deal with polynomials and I vaguely remember responses either here or a commmunity.wolfram.com stating so.

Comment: Well, if `Minimize` only handles polynomials, I think this should clearly been stated in the documentation. I couldn't find anything along these lines, but I of course understand that a general minimization algorithm would be hard to implement.

Comment: "Obviously, the answer should have been {0, {a -> 0}}" cannot be `True` with the constraint given as `a > 0` which precludes `a == 0`. Although, even correcting the constraint does not resolve the basic issue.

Comment: Thank you Bob! I played around with different constraints and the one mentioned in the question is obviously wrong. I corrected the question.

Answer (score 2):

How about approaching the minization using derivatives?

```
Solve[D[a^2*Exp[-b^2], a] == 0, a]
{{a -> 0}}
```

Comment: That's a good solution, but I'm still surprised that Mathematica cannot solve the original problem. I guess I underestimate the difficulty of such code.