# Parallel function evaluation for minimal value

Tags: performance-tuning, evaluation, mathematical-optimization, parallelization

I am asking myself, if the evaluation of a function `f` looking for a minimal value over a discrete set of values can be parallelize (brute scan for a potential minimal value over a rectangular region with specified resolution). Is it possible or just not suitable for parallel computing do to the need to always compare to a reference which needs to happen in the main kernel? As far as I understood it in

[Why won't Parallelize speed up my code?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48295/why-wont-parallelize-speed-up-my-code)

the forced evaluation in the main kernel with `SetSharedVariable` can cause a significant lost in speed, which I think is the case in my horribly parallelized evaluation (see below). Any suggestions? I am pretty sure, I am just not seeing the obvious perspective. I dont want to use NMinimize, I only want to scan rapidly (if possible also in parallel) a rectangular region with specified resolution and pick up the minimal value. Sorry, if this is a duplicate, I was not able to find an answer. Thanks.

Minimal example:

Function:

```
f = Sin[x - z + Pi/4] + (y - 2)^2 + 13;
```

Sequential evaluation with do:

```
Clear[fmin]
fmin
n = 10^1*2;
fmin = f /. {x -> 0, y -> 0, z -> 0};
fmin // N
start = DateString[]
Do[
 ftemp = f /. {x -> xp, y -> yp, z -> zp};
 If[ftemp < fmin, fmin = ftemp];
 , {xp, 0, Pi, Pi/n}
 , {yp, -2, 4, 6/n}
 , {zp, -Pi, Pi, 2*Pi/n}
 ]
end = DateString[]
DateDifference[start, end, {"Minute", "Second"}]
fmin // N
```

Horribly parallelized evaluation

```
Clear[fmin]
fmin
n = 10^1*2;
fmin = f /. {x -> 0, y -> 0, z -> 0};
fmin // N
SetSharedVariable[fmin];
start = DateString[]
ParallelDo[
 ftemp = f /. {x -> xp, y -> yp, z -> zp};
 If[ftemp < fmin, fmin = ftemp];
 , {xp, 0, Pi, Pi/n}
 , {yp, -2, 4, 6/n}
 , {zp, -Pi, Pi, 2*Pi/n}
 ]
end = DateString[]
DateDifference[start, end, {"Minute", "Second"}]
fmin // N
```

Comment: I guess `z -> yp` is a typo and should be `z -> zp`? Are there any reasons why you are using, e.g.,  `f /. {x -> 0, y -> 0, z -> 0}` and don't have `f` defined using [`SetDeleyed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html)(`f[x_, y_, z_] := Sin[x - z + Pi/4] + (y - 2)^2 + 13`)?

Comment: Yes, that is a typo, I will correct it. No, no real reason, I just like to use sometimes expressions instead of functions. Hmmm, ... would a function evaluate faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't compare to a *single (shared) main-kernel variable* (`fmin`) on each kernel.  Instead, allow each kernel to find the smallest of the points *it* has checked. Let each kernel have its own private `fmin`.  Then you'll have `$KernelCount` candidates for the minimum.  Finally select the smallest of these.

[`ParallelCombine`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParallelCombine.html) is made for precisely this type of approach.  It may be a good idea to use `Method -> "CoarsestGrained"`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was not aware of ParallelCombine, or I overread it.

Comment: Do you mean using `ParallelCombine[Do[ftemp = f /. {x -> xp, y -> yp, z -> yp};
  If[ftemp < fmin, fmin = ftemp];, {xp, 0, Pi, Pi/n}, {yp, -2, 4, 
   6/n}, {zp, -Pi, Pi, 2*Pi/n}], Method -> "CoarsestGrained"]`? Just want your confirmation before adding a speed comparison.

Comment: @Karsten7. No, not quite.  I just implemented what I meant and it is terribly slow.  Then I remembered that I noticed before that ParallelCombine is much, much slower than it is supposed to be.  A naive reimplementation in terms of ParallelSubmit is much faster.  I searched my mailbox and found when I reported this to WRI more than a year ago.  They never responded.  I'm too tired now but I'll try to write this up tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward parallelization of you code without a slowdown due to using `SetSharedVariable` is to use:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := Sin[x - z + Pi/4] + (y - 2)^2 + 13

n = 10^1*2.;

LaunchKernels[];

AbsoluteTiming[
 ParallelEvaluate[fmin = f[0., 0., 0.];];
 ParallelDo[
  If[# < fmin, fmin = #] &@f[xp, yp, zp];, 
  {xp, 0., Pi, Pi/n}, {yp, -2., 4., 6./n}, {zp, -Pi, Pi, 2*Pi/n}];
 fmin = Min[ParallelEvaluate[fmin]]
 ]
```

$\ $`{0.0699944, 12.01}`

For comparison:

```
SetSharedVariable[fmin]

ParallelDo[ftemp = f /. {x -> xp, y -> yp, z -> yp};
  If[ftemp < fmin, fmin = ftemp];, {xp, 0, Pi, Pi/n}, {yp, -2, 4, 6/n}, 
  {zp, -Pi, Pi, 2*Pi/n}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

$\ $`{34.0979, Null}`

---

Your `fmin` is just the `Min` of all the `ftemp` you are computing. Therefore, you could replace your `Do` loop with something like

```
Min[Table[
  f /. {x -> xp, y -> yp, z -> yp}, {xp, 0, Pi, Pi/n}, {yp, -2, 4, 6/n}, 
  {zp, -Pi, Pi, 2*Pi/n}]]
```

And for parallelization change `Table` to `ParallelTable`:

```
Min[ParallelTable[
  f /. {x -> xp, y -> yp, z -> yp}, {xp, 0, Pi, Pi/n}, {yp, -2, 4, 6/n}, 
  {zp, -Pi, Pi, 2*Pi/n}]]
```

---

Speed comparison:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 fmin = Min[
   Table[N@f /. {x -> xp, y -> yp, z -> yp}, {xp, 0, Pi, Pi/n}, {yp, -2, 4, 6/n}, 
    {zp, -Pi, Pi, 2*Pi/n}]]
 ]
```

$\ $`{0.261962, 12.0522}`

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 fmin = Min[
   ParallelTable[
    N@f /. {x -> xp, y -> yp, z -> yp}, {xp, 0, Pi, Pi/n}, {yp, -2, 4, 6/n}, 
    {zp, -Pi, Pi, 2*Pi/n}]]
 ]
```

$\ $`{0.120665, 12.0522}`

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 fmin = Min[
   ParallelTable[
    N@f /. {x -> xp, y -> yp, z -> yp}, {xp, 0, Pi, Pi/n}, {yp, -2, 4, 6/n}, 
    {zp, -Pi, Pi, 2*Pi/n}, Method -> "CoarsestGrained"]]
 ]
```

$\ $`{0.0999586, 12.0522}`

Comment: Hmmm, but what about when I go up with the resolution? The table will explode in resources, which I am not interested in. I only need a scalar value, I mean the minimal value. Or is this not important since the table is not assigned to any symbol and therefore deleted after the completition of Min[ ] ?

Comment: @MauricioLobos Please see my latest edit for a version that will use less memory. Using `ParallelTable` consumes more memory, even more than using `Table`. It depends on the amount of your RAM, if you will hit a memory or a time limit first, as computation time also explodes.

Comment: @MauricioLobos Using `ParallelTable` makes it possible to visualize the intermediate data ([for the given example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssSee.png)) and to find the intervals in which increasing the resolution makes most sense.

Comment: Thank you. May be this is also something NMinimize does if you use the `Method->"RandomSearch"`.

Comment: @Mauricio and Karsten: there appears to be a bug in 10.3 which causes significant slowdowns with paralellelization.  It's been giving me a really hard time before I remembered [this thread](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/583220).  [Witness](https://www.dropbox.com/s/026x3a30ywhacrl/Screenshot%202015-10-30%2012.48.13.png?dl=0)  Sorry, I don't have time to get to the bottom of this today, but I'll get back to it later

Comment: @Szabolcs Wow, those slowdowns are impressive. Thanks for the information. Since I still have 10.0.2 I think I will stay with it until 10.4 or 11.

Comment: @MauricioLobos I'm using *Mathematica* v10.3 on Windows 10 and don't witness such slowdowns.

Comment: @Karsten7. You mean compared to 10.2?

Comment: @Szabolcs I don't have 10.2 installed anymore, but my timings are in the same range as your 10.2 timings. I just did a test run using v9.0.1 and it's only 12% faster.